# Does this classify as Information retrieval?

Tags: information-retrieval

I’m trying to figure out if what I’m doing would classify as Information Retrieval. According to [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7181/relation-and-difference-between-information-retrieval-and-information-extraction) Thread:

> **Information retrieval** is **based on a query** - you specify what information you need and it is returned in human understandable form.

I’ve a script that reads unstructured text (titles of books) and extracts names (which I gathered in a list beforehand) from the titles and outputs a CSV with all matched names. Would that be a simple use case of Information Retrieval or is this called „tagging“? If both not, what would one call this technique?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider that a form of information retrieval, if you want.  It sounds like keyword matching, so not one of the more sophisticated forms of information retrieval, but sometimes the simplest solutions are the best.

I wouldn't worry too much about the name.  There's no strict, hard-and-fast definition of exactly what counts and what doesn't.  The term serves as an aid for communication, and to my way of thinking, it sounds fine to consider what you are doing as a form of information retrieval.